# How to get minute from string datetime by javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string: "12:30:00 PM" and "1:30:00 PM". How can I get minute from 2 string. String of hour maybe 1 or 2 character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var time = '12:30:00 PM',
    hours = time.split(':')[0],
    minutes = time.split(':')[1],
    seconds = time.split(':')[2].split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest to program, I think, is to just [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the time string:

```
var time = "12:30:00 PM";
var minutes = time.split(":")[1];
```

You can also scan for the two `":"` characters using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and then use [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)  to extract the relevant text, but that's a lot more work. Simple is better.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), you can use a [duration](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/):

```
var s = "12:30:00 PM"; 
var minutes = moment.duration(s).minutes(); // duration, so AM/PM is meaningless.
```

or [parse with an exact format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

```
var minutes = moment(s, "h:mm:ss a").minutes();
```

Comment: +1 for a semantically correct solution. String manipulation may be more efficient, but we are working with a date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var min1 = "12:30:00 PM".split(':')[1];
alert(min1);
var min2 = "1:5:00 PM".split(':')[1];
alert(min2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do like this also,

```
str = "12:30:00 PM"
date = new Date("1/1/1900 "+str)
alert(date.getMinutes())
alert(date.getHours())
```